# Preemptive SSTF algorithm

Tags: algorithm

What happens in preemptive SSTF algorithm if the arriving process has the same burst time (shortest) as the currently running process at that instance? Will running process continue to run or the processor will switch to the arriving process?

Example: At time instance 4, P1 has the remaining time of 6 ms and a new process p2 arrives with a burst of 6 ms, will P1 continue to run or process will switch to P2?

Answer (score 1):

That is entirely system dependent. It may break the tie using the smallest arrival time first or it may be simply the priority of the jobs. In general it is the priority which is determined by number of factors. That saves you from stucking a process in same state for long. These are the common way using which the problem is resolved.

So long story short `it depends on implementation`.